# ¿Cómo usar onchange de un select en jquery para abrir una modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un  `select` con con el evento `on.('change')` de `jquery`, pero al seleccionar una opción y cierro la modal, y vuelvo a seleccionar la misma opción no abre la modal (Bootstrap). ¿Hay una forma u otro evento con el que pueda realizar esta acción?

```
 $('#combo-ubicacion').on('change', function (event) {
                TipoUbicacionSelected = $('#ubicacion :selected').val();
                if (TipoUbicacionSelected == "0") {
                    //muestro otra modal
                }
                if (TipoUbicacionSelected == "1") {
                    //muestro modal
                } else if (TipoUbicacionSelected == "2") {

                    //otraaaaa
                }
            });
```

Comment: Debes incluir el código que estás usando para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida en la comunidad, ademas el onchange es un evento que se ejecuta cuando el valor de tu elemento cambia, si estas seleccionando el mismo valor actual ese evento nunca se va a ejecutar por que sencillamente el valor no ha cambiado

Comment: Ok si, por eso pregunto si existe otro evento? @CamiloVasquez

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647282/is-there-an-onselect-event-or-equivalent-for-html-select

Answer (score 2):

Lo que se me ocurre que puedas hacer para que tu evento `change` se ejecute sin problemas es simplemente que cuando cierres la modal el valor del select se restablezca a 0.

```
$("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#combo-ubicacion').val('');
});
```

Otro evento que podrías usar seria un `onblur` pero tendrías que seleccionar una opción y salir de foco del elemento para que se pudiera ejecutar por lo cual personalmente no lo veo muy usable en tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esta respuesta es usando bootstrap

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Ejemplo</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
body {
padding-top: 1em;
} 
</style> <div class="container-fluid">
  
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#flipFlop">
Click
</button>

<!-- The modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="flipFlop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel">Flip-flop</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
A type of open-toed sandal.
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
  
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Popper -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified Bootstrap JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero no estoy preguntando como abrir una modal con un boton.